# Animation with large number of sprites in Cocos2d iOS?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-sheet, zwoptex

I have to **animate(dancing)** a **character(guy)** for about 6-7 seconds i.e **500-600 frames**. I have done animation before by creating spritesheets using ***zwoptex*** and then loading it with ***CCSpriteFrameCache && CCSpriteBatchNode*** with the help of [The Great Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32045/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d-2-x). But in this case frames are heavy in number i am not sure if iOS device will be able to sustain it. What is the best process to animate all these frames with as **little overhead** as possible. Can i change the **fps** while animating? any idea anyone??

Answer (score 0):

Here I put code That use for add Animated Image Without use **TexturePacker**:

```
CCSprite *dog = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"dog1.gif"];
        dog.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:dog z:2];

        NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for( int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            NSString* file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dog%d.gif", i];
            CCTexture2D* texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:file];
            CGSize texSize = texture.contentSize;
            CGRect texRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, texSize.width, texSize.height);
            CCSpriteFrame* frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:texture rect:texRect];
            [animFrames addObject:frame];
        }
        CCAnimation * animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:animFrames];
        animation.delayPerUnit = 0.07f;
        animation.restoreOriginalFrame = YES;

        CCAnimate *animAction  = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation]];
        [dog runAction:animAction];
```

Try with This code, I'm not sure might be helpful in your case: